# Assign Dynamic ngModel and perform Loop calculation

Tags: angular, for-loop, ionic-framework

I have a table with input fields of quantities and prices where the user can add rows dynamically. I want to calculate the total price of each item (quantity * price) and then add all these total prices together for the grand total price.

How could I assign ngModel name for the user added fields and retrieve them in a calculation that loop through each row?

Please help! Thank you so much!!!

**Here is my code is html:**

```
<tr>
   <td>
     <ion-item>
       <ion-input type="text" placeholder="Item"></ion-input>
     </ion-item>
   </td>
   <td>
     <ion-item>
       <ion-input type="text" placeholder="Qty." [(ngModel)]="quantity1"></ion-input>
     </ion-item>
   </td>
   <td>
     <ion-item>
       <ion-input type="text" placeholder="Price" [(ngModel)]="price1"></ion-input>
     </ion-item>
   </td>
</tr>
```

**User adding row**

```
<tr *ngFor="let row of rows" ng-repeat="row in rows">
  <td>
    <ion-item>
      <ion-input type="text" placeholder="Item"></ion-input>
    </ion-item>
  </td>
  <td>
    <ion-item>
      <ion-input type="text" placeholder="Qty."></ion-input>
    </ion-item>
  </td>
  <td>
    <ion-item>
      <ion-input type="text" placeholder="Price"></ion-input>
    </ion-item>
  </td>
</tr>
```

Comment: Your `rows` variable already contains all the rows, why don't you just sum up those values and show the result?

Comment: Hi! I put them there as a placeholder. Essentially I would like to provide 1 fixed row allow user to add more rows if needed, and do calculations from there.